# is there a difference between meteor angular:angular and urigo:angular-meteor packages?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to put together an app, that uses both meteor and angular

I see, what appears to be two different base angular packages: one named angular:angular, and another named urigo:angular-meteor

The page for angular:angular says, that that is the actual angularJS repo, in which case, assuming that means that angular:angular is not an isopack) I'm not even sure on how to add that to a meteor app.

Which one of these should I be using to add angular functionality to a meteor app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urigo:angular-meteor is the package that you can use for development in meteor + angular. check out this [video by uri himself](http://m.youtube.com/watchhttp://m.youtube.com/watch?v=uFmf-DeCdEE) explaining thoroughly about the package and development using it also.